# Affecting an int to a char array , why does printf shows this?

Tags: c

With this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

  char buffer[64];
  int check;
  int i = 2;

  buffer[-2] = i;
  printf("%x\n",buffer[-2]);

  i=25;
  buffer[-2] = i;
  printf("%x\n",buffer[-2]);

  i=255; 
  buffer[-2] = i;
  printf("%x\n",buffer[-2]);   

  return 0;
}
```

I get this output (compilation with gcc and `-m32` option).

```
2
19
ffffffff
```

So, I can understand the two first values (2 and 19), but I really don't understand the 3rd as 255 is equal to ff and not ffffffff.

Do you have any idea why it's displayed like this ?

Thank you

**p.s:** Please don't suggest to affect "chars" to a "char" array, this code is just for training, thank you.

**p.s (bis)**: please don't say it's not valid, because if it is, why are the 1rst two output of the program in accordance with the code ??

I compiled this code with `gcc -m32 -o code code.c`

Comment: Why are you using `-2` as index?

Comment: `buffer[-2] = i;` wat

Comment: valid indices for buffer are `0` through `63`. Your program causes undefined behaviour, therefore any output is possible

Comment: @M.M Please try youself, it work just find, see the 2 first outpu of buffer[-2], they are valid

Comment: Apart from the undefined behavior: `char` is a *signed* integer on your platform, and printing it with `%x` does a sign extension to `-1` which is then printed in hex as `ffffffff`. So you would get the same output when using `buffer[+2]`.

Comment: @gfd78Fgi, nops, a negative index is only allowed in cases like: `char buffer[64]; char *ptr = buffer + 2; ptr[-2] = i;`

Comment: please see [what is undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) before you attract even more downvotes

Comment: @MartinR using wrong format specifier is also undefined behaviour. On OP's system the "sign extension" is likely to come from default argument promotions, not from `%x`

Comment: @M.M: Well, that is what I meant (perhaps expressed badly): `char` is promoted to `int`  with sign extension in the variable argument list, and that is printed with `%x` as `ffffffff`.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have any idea why it's displayed like this ?

No, because your program has **undefined behavior**:

```
buffer[-2] = i; 
//     ^^
```

You're accessing `buffer` out of bounds, causing **UB** - therefore *anything can happen*.

Comment: Please try youself before telling this, it perfectly works !

Comment: @gfd78Fgi: sure thing. Here's [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/et7sZYKEBTVwYwhw) telling you that you're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
 buffer[-2] = i; //invalid; out of range
```

It is not valid, because you would be accessing memory outside the bounds of the array. Please see this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking about the behaviour of this code:

```
int i = 255;
char c = i;
printf("%x\n", c);
```

The reason it prints `ffffffff` is because `printf` is a vararg function so all integer-types smaller than int are promoted to int. So you could have written:

```
int i = 255;
char c = i;
printf("%x\n", (int)c);
```

Then the question comes, why is `(int)c` the same as `ffffffff`. It is because `c` is assigned `ff`, which is beyond its limits of -128 to 127. It is wrapped to `-1`. It is then converted to the int value `-1`, and the int value `-1` is coded as `ffffffff`.

**Note:** As many others have written, your program has undefined behaviour. This means that your program may print other things, or crash, when run on a different compiler, a different computer, or even a different version of your compiler. It is considered bad practise to include undefined behaviour in a program.

Comment: For completeness it should be pointed out that on a system with unsigned `char` there will be no sign extension and the output will be `ff`.